# Can a JSON schema validator be killed with this schema?

Tags: jsonschema

I tried this out with some JSON schema validators and some fail, but the problem is to figure out how much memory a validator uses that causes it to choke and be killed.

It turns out that we can implement finite state machines in JSON schema. To do so, the FSM nodes are object schemas and the FSM edges are a set of JSON Pointers wrapped in an `anyOf`. The whole thing is rather simple to do, but being able to do this has some consequences: what if we create an FSM that requires 2^*N* time or memory (depth first search or breadth first search, respectively) given a JSON schema with *N* definitions and some input to validate?

So let's create a JSON Schema with *N* definitions to implement a non-deterministic finite state machine (NFA) over an alphabet of two symbols `a` and `b`. All we need to do is to encode the regex
`(a{N}|a(a|b+){0,N-1}b)*x`, where `x` denotes the end. In the worst case, the NFA for this regex takes 2^*N* time to match text or 2^*N* memory (e.g. when converted to a deterministic finite state machine). Now notice that the word `abbx` can be represented by a JSON pointer `a/b/b/x` which in JSON is equivalent to `{"a":{"b":{"b":{"x":true}}}}`.

To encode this NFA as a schema, we first add a definition for state "0":

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "$ref": "#/definitions/0",
  "definitions": {
    "0": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "a": { "$ref": "#/definitions/1" },
        "x": { "type": "boolean" }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
```

Then we add *N*-1 definitions for each state `<DEF>` to the schema where `<DEF>` is enumerated "1", "2", "3", ... "*N*-1":

```
    "<DEF>": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "a": { "$ref": "#/definitions/<DEF>+1" },
        "b": {
          "anyOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/0" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/<DEF>" }
          ]
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
```

where "`<DEF>`+1" wraps back to "0" when `<DEF>` is equal to *N*-1.

This "NFA" on a two-letter alphabet has *N* states, only one initial and one
final state. The equivalent minimal DFA has 2^*N* (2 to the power *N*) states.

This means that in the worst case, a validator that uses this schema either must be taking 2^*N* time or use 2^*N* memory "cells" to validate the input.

I don't see where this logic can go wrong, unless validators take shortcuts to approximate the validity checking.

I found [this here](http://www.sjot.org).

Comment: Working example: https://runkit.com/esp/583ca4c49f00610014777a8b . The problem will be a stack size, for all validators I think, unless some of them implements recursion internally which is highly unlikely.
Seems a bit theoretic problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in principle you are right. I am not 100% sure about the schema construction you've described, but theoretically it should be possible to construct a schema which required ^N time or space, exactly for the reasons you describe.

Practically most schema processors will probably just try to recursively validate `anyOf`. So, that would be exponential time.